# возникает ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'search' of null после подключения twitter.com/widgets.js

Tags: javascript

Дано две кнопки, одна из них твиттер, другая обычная. Я хочу устанавливать свои параметры для ссылки и значения для атрибута `data-text`

Все работает, но если подключить (что необходимо, чтобы работала твиттер-кнопка)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

то сразу перестает работать код, не получается ничего уже из этого сделать.

```
document.getElementById("myTweet").search = param;
document.getElementById("myTweet").setAttribute('data-text', "someValue");
```

сразу ругается и выдает ошибки:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'search' of null pen.js:13
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Т.е. убираю скрипт `widgets.js` - мой скрипт работает, устанавливает параметры для ссылки, значения для атрибута `data-text`, но перестает работать твиттер-кнопка. Подключаю - наоборот мой код не работает, не могу установить параметры и значения для атрибута. Как исправить или может есть иной путь.

ниже ссылка на код
[`https://codepen.io/sibkedr/pen/GEJWdL`](https://codepen.io/sibkedr/pen/GEJWdL)

```js
$("document").ready(function() {

  var count = 0;
  $("#btnSetParam").on("click", function() {
    var param = "text=" + encodeURIComponent('"new Value-"') + count++;
      setNewParam(param);
  });

  function setNewParam(param) {
    document.getElementById("myTweet").search = param;
    console.log(document.getElementById("myTweet").search);

    document.getElementById("myTweet").setAttribute('data-text', "someValue");
    var dataAttr = document.getElementById("myTweet").getAttribute('data-text');
    console.log(dataAttr);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container mt-5 px-2 py-2">
  <a id="myTweet" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=quote" class="twitter-hashtag-button" data-text="Here a quote" data-show-count="false">Tweet #quote</a>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
  <button id="btnSetParam" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
</div>
```

Comment: В изначальном документе он как раз есть. Ссылка заменяется на код плагина после инициализации. Отсюда и все проблемы. После отработки твитер-кода ссылка исчезает

Comment: Используйте, например, айди `twitter-widget-0` для первого виджета в документе вместо `myTweet`.

Comment: Да с twitter-widget-0 работает, спасибо!